# Dynamically add markers on changed map - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map with markers where the retail locations are.

It works fine.

If the user change the map focus by drag and drop (change the map extract) 
I want to add dynamically new markers if in this map extract is a shop.

I have no idea, where I find such a example or something else.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865235/how-to-dynamically-change-a-google-maps-marker-after-its-added and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844626/dynamically-add-google-map-v3-markers-using-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to load the initial batch of markers and then listen for the **"bounds_changed"** event. When that event fires simply get the new coordinates and zoom level and load markers accordingly.

You can find an example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    //Get the new location and zoom parameters
    //and print the new markers
});
```